# AspNet Core MVC view page not loading propery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

**Dot NET CORE**  I am trying to add MVC view PAGE in MVC CORE web API soultion. I have added the controller and view but as soon as I try to access it, it gives run time error as below.

While creating the project if I select Web Application everything works fine .But I have an existing rest API Project and this makes me create two project. I think we can extend the same project to host Rest API as well as web page if needed. Cant we ?

[image: I am continuously getting this run time error]

**Startup.cs**

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseOAuthValidation();
            app.UseOpenIddict();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAutoMapper();
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddOpenIddict<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()

                .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
                .AllowPasswordFlow()
                .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
                .DisableHttpsRequirement()

                .AddEphemeralSigningKey();
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }
```

**Project.json**

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "debugType": "portable"
  },
  "dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-alpha2-0448",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-alpha2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0",
    "AutoMapper": "5.1.1",
    "AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel": "1.0.0-rc3-003121",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "datalayer": "1.0.0.0",
    "Common": "1.0.0-*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": { }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [ "wwwroot" ],
    "includeFiles": [ "appsettings.json" ]
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public class ActivationController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View (Index.cshtml)

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

Comment: What's the code in the cshtml file?

Comment: <h1>Hello world!</h1>   thats all

Comment: Please, update your answer with your project.json, Startup.cs, your MVC Controller and your View.

Comment: Updated in the question. Please have a look

Comment: Are you using a other repositories besides Nuget for your packages? I could not find the "OpenIddict" package, for example.

Comment: It's there in dependencies  .. "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-alpha2-0448"

Comment: While creating the project if I select Web Application everything works fine .But I have an existing rest API Project and this makes me create two project.   I think we can extend the same project to host Rest API as well as web page if needed. Cant we ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems we need to set  preserveCompilationContext to true in project.json  . It's necessary for runtime compilation of Razor views .

```
  "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "debugType": "portable",
        "preserveCompilationContext": true
      },
```